# C# brief delay after clicking image to display new source

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got an Windows.Controls.Image that when clicked needs to change its source and have that displayed for x milliseconds before then navigating to a new Page. I tried using Thread.Sleep(200) after changing the source but no matter how I tried to force a redraw the changed source was not displayed and then when the sleep was over it instantly changed page. Does anyone know how I can do this? Cheers!

```
private void ButtonClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         Image button = (Image)sender;
         buttons[button.Name].Source = ImageResizer.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"D:\buttons\" + button.Name + ".png"), buttonSize);
         NavigationService.Navigate(new UpgradeQuiz());
    }
```

Comment: You may start a DispatcherTimer with a Tick handler that does the Navigate call (and stops the timer). Out of curiosity, why are you using `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile` (from WinForms) in a WPF application, instead of directly loading a WPF BitmapImage from a local file URI?

Comment: I only did a very brief amount of c# coding many years ago and have forgotten most. A lot of the stuff I'm doing is learning with help from the web. My ImageResizer.ResizeImage function takes a System.Drawing.Image, which is why I'm using it. The code is here if you are interested: http://pastebin.com/s3VsHkhB As I learn more I am going back to refactor in best practice.

Comment: You won't typically use WinForms classes in a WPF application. Without having had a look at your ResizeImage  method, I'd suggest to rewrite it to use only classes from `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`.

Comment: I did try WPF for resizing but I needed to use bicubic to get the required image quality. I could not find how to do bicubic resizing with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can asynchronously wait:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

But you should make your handler `async`:

```
private async void ButtonClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // async after private
{
     Image button = (Image)sender;
     buttons[button.Name].Source = ImageResizer.ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"D:\buttons\" + button.Name + ".png"), buttonSize);
     await Task.Delay(2000);
     NavigationService.Navigate(new UpgradeQuiz());
}
```